# Understanding skeleton_markers message

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using skeleton_tracker and i do not understand why  orientation has 4 values (x,y,z,w). and i don't know what is the confidence value.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194121/understanding-skeleton_markers-message/) by [idavico](https://answers.ros.org/users/20379/idavico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[skeleton_markers/Skeleton](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/skeleton_markers/html/msg/Skeleton.html) message orientation is in Quaternion form.

Quaternion gives rotation  [image: image description]  about a vector [image: image description].

[image: Quaternion]

this [QA](http://answers.ros.org/question/9772/quaternions-orientation-representation/) is helpful.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1